# How do I change the variable in a concrete decorator during run-time in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

Here's the situation.

The Items abstract class with a JLabel `label`, and the `display()` function to show the item on the screen by adding the JLabel to JPanel:

```
public abstract class Items {

    public JLabel label;

    // to add label to panel (display on screen)
    public abstract void display(JPanel panel);
}
```

A concrete implementation:

```
public class ConcreteItem extends Items {

    public ConcreteItem() {
        // set the label of concrete item
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://..."));
        this.label = new JLabel(icon);
    }
    @Override
    public void display(JPanel panel) {
        panel.add(this.label);
    }
}
```

The decorator:

```
public abstract class ItemDecorator extends Items {

    public Items decoratedItem;

    public ItemDecorator(Items decoratedItem){
        super();
        this.decoratedItem = decoratedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void display(JPanel panel) {
        this.item.display(panel);
    }

}
```

and the concrete decorator:

```
public class ConcreteDecorator extends ItemDecorator {

    public ConcreteDecorator(Items decoratedItem) {
        super(decoratedItem);

        // set the label of concrete decorator
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://..."));
        this.label = new JLabel(icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void display(JPanel panel) {
        super.display(panel);
        panel.add(this.label); // add label of concrete decorator to the screen
    }
}
```

and the client class:

```
public class Client {
    public Client() {

        Jpanel panel = new JPanel();

        // create item with decorators (these are created somewhere else, furthur being returned to Client class)
        ConcreteItem concreteItem = new ConcreteItem();
        ConcreteDecorator decorator = new ConcreteDecorator(concreteItem);

        // and this is the only stuff in Client class
        Items item = decorator;

        // display all elements on screen
        item.display(panel);
    }
}
```

So when I create an `Items` object decorated by a `ConcreteDecorator`, the `display()` function should add all the labels to panel. And I'd like to set the visibility of the label in the ConcreteDecorator to `false`, i.e. `label.setVisible(false)`, during run-time, in order to remove it from the screen. How can I do so from the Client class with only `item` object?

Comment: Replace `implements Items` to `extends Items`. You cannot implement a class

Comment: Sorry my bad 

Answer (score 0):

Since `flag` is a public field, you can change it anywhere you have access to an instance of `Items`, like:

```
public class ConcreteDecorator extends ItemDecorator {

    public ConcreteDecorator(Items item) {
        super(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        item.flag = false; // <<< change flag here
        super.display();
        System.out.print("Adding decorators to Item...");
    }
}
```

Besides of the decorator pattern, you should have much more strict visibility; use `private` and `protected` whereever possible.

Comment: thanks for answering! but what if I want to change it from client class? So what you mean is to call ```display``` function from the top decorator class again?

Comment: I think I don't get your problem, sorry.

Comment: sorry about my bad description. I've updated the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

As `flag` is a public field, you should just be able to call it from the `Client` class:

```
item.flag = false;
```

Kind of a weird class hierarchy though...

Comment: I think everyone has their own copy of ```flag``` as long as they're the descendent  class of ```Items```. my intention is to set the ```flag``` of concreteDecorator to false, which is to remove it from the screen. Will directly setting ```item.flag = false``` do so?

Comment: Maybe you should further specify your intention. What is it _exactly_ that you want to achieve? As far as I can see, the `flag` field is never read, so not clear what the intention is...

Comment: You're right. I've updated my problem with better details and intentions.